Exchange one row and then find columns such that to have invertible matrices with these specific rows and columns
Given the natural numbers $n, l, m$ such that $n \geqslant l \geqslant m$
and consider the two matrices:
\begin{align*}
A
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,m} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,m} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{l,1} & a_{l,2} & \cdots & a_{l,m}
\end{pmatrix}_{l \times m}
\text{ with } rank(A) = m
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
B
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & \cdots & b_{1,l} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & \cdots & b_{2,l} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{n,1} & b_{n,2} & \cdots & b_{n,l}
\end{pmatrix}_{n \times l}
\text{ with } rank(B) = l.
\end{align*}
Note:

$[n] : = \{ 1 , 2 , \ldots , n \} \quad , \quad [l] : = \{ 1 , 2 , \ldots , l \} \quad , \quad [m] : = \{ 1 , 2 , \ldots , m \}$.
$I_{1} - I_{2} := I_{1} \setminus I_{2}$.
Take $\displaystyle{I = \{ r_{1} , r_{2} , \ldots , r_{m} \} \subseteq [ n ]}$ and $\displaystyle{J = \{ c_{1} , c_{2} , \ldots , c_{m} \} \subseteq [ l ]}$, then $B_{I, J}$ is the matrix $B$ with rows the numbers $\displaystyle{r_{1} , r_{2} , \ldots , r_{m}}$ and columns the numbers $\displaystyle{c_{1} , c_{2} , \ldots , c_{m}}$. (Same for the matrix $A_{J, [m]}$).


Problem: Let's \begin{align*} I_{1} \quad \text{and} \quad I_{2} \quad \text{with} \quad |I_{1}| = |I_{2}| = m \qquad \text{and} \qquad \color{orange} x \color{black} \in I_{1} - I_{2} \end{align*} such
that \begin{align*} \exists J_{1} \quad \text{and} \quad \exists J_{2} \quad \text{with} \quad |J_{1}| = |J_{2}| = m \\ \text{such that} \\ \det B_{I_{f} , J_{f} } \neq 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \det A_{J_{f} , [m]} \neq 0 \quad \text{ for } f=1,2. \end{align*} Show that: there
is an element $\color{magenta} y \color{black} \in I_{2} - I_{1}$ such
that for $I : = (I_{1} - \color{orange} x \color{black}) \cup $
$\color{magenta} y$ exists an m-element set $J$ with $\det A_{J , [m]} \neq 0$ and $\det B_{I , J} \neq 0$.

My attempt:

We want to show that: $\exists \color{magenta} y \color{black} \in I_{2} - I_{1}$ such that for $I : = ( I_{1} - \color{orange}x ) \cup \color{magenta} y $ exists an $m-$element set $J$ with $\det A_{J , [m]} \neq 0$ and $\det B_{I , J} \neq 0$.

We know that: $\displaystyle{\exists J_{1}}$
and
$\displaystyle{\exists J_{2}}$, with $|J_{1}| = | J_{2} | = m$, such that
$\displaystyle{\det B_{I_{f} , J_{f} } \neq 0}$ and $\displaystyle{\det A_{J_{f} , [m]} \neq 0}$ for $f=1,2$.

For that $J_{1} , J_{2}$, we have $2$ invertible matrices $m \times m$ in $A$.

Suppose, by contradiction, $\displaystyle{\forall y \in I_{2} - I_{1}}$ and for all $m-$element sets $J$ we have $\det A_{J , [m]} = 0$ or $\det B_{I , J} = 0$.

Take $J = J_{1}$: since $\det A_{J_{1} , [m]} \neq 0$, that implies $\det B_{I , J_{1}} = 0$ for all $y \in I_{2} - I_{1}$
similar
take $J = J_{2}$: since $\det A_{J_{2} , [m]} \neq 0$, that implies $\det B_{I , J_{2}} = 0$ for all $y \in I_{2} - I_{1}$.

That means: each row in a matrix $B$ from $I_{2}$ is linearly dependent with the others rows from $I_{1} - \color{orange} x$ at columns $J_{1}$ and $J_{2}$.


How could we solve this problem? I've stuck...Any ideas?

We can prove the above for $m=2$.
\begin{align*}
A
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
a_{l,1} & a_{l,2}
\end{pmatrix}_{l \times 2}
\text{ with } rank(A) = 2
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
B
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & \cdots & b_{1,l} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & \cdots & b_{2,l} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{n,1} & b_{n,2} & \cdots & b_{n,l}
\end{pmatrix}_{n \times l}
\text{ with } rank(B) = l.
\end{align*}
Let's \begin{align*} I_{1} = \{ 1 \leq i_{11} < i_{12} \leq n \} \quad \text{and} \quad I_{2} = \{ 1 \leq i_{21} < i_{22} \leq n \} \end{align*} such that \begin{align*} \exists J_{1} = \{ 1 \leq j_{12} < j_{12} \leq l\} \quad \text{and} \quad \exists J_{2} = \{ 1 \leq j_{21} < j_{21} \leq l\} \\ \text{such that} \\ \det B_{I_{f} , J_{f} } \neq 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \det A_{J_{f} , [2]} \neq 0 \quad \text{ for } f=1,2. \end{align*}

If $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ have a common element, say $\displaystyle{i_{12} = i_{21}}$, then the only element in $I_{1} - I_{2} = \{ i_{11} \}$ is $x = i_{11}$.
Moreover $\displaystyle{I_{2} - I_{1} = \{ i_{22} \}}$, that means the only possible $y$ is $\displaystyle{y = i_{22}}$.
Therefore the $\displaystyle{I}$ is $\displaystyle{I = ( I_{1} - x ) \cup y = \{ i_{12} , i_{22} \} = I_{2}}$, so there is $J = J_{2}$ with the require property.
If $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ do not have a common elements. Then $\displaystyle{I_{1} - I_{2} = I_{1}}$ and $\displaystyle{I_{2} - I_{1} = I_{2}}$.
Pick $\displaystyle{x \in I_{1} - I_{2} = I_{1}}$ randomly, say $\displaystyle{x = i_{11}}$ or $\displaystyle{i_{12}}$. Take $\displaystyle{x = i_{11}}$, so $\displaystyle{I_{1} - x = \{ i_{12} \}}$.
We want to find $\displaystyle{y \in I_{2} - I_{1} = I_{2}}$, say $\displaystyle{y = i_{21}}$ or $\displaystyle{i_{22}}$, such that for $\displaystyle{I : = ( I_{1} - x ) \cup y = \{ i_{11} , y \}}$ exists an 2-element set $J$ with $\det A_{J , [2]} \neq 0$ and $\det B_{I , J} \neq 0$.
The matrix $A$ has $\displaystyle{l-2}$ linear dependent rows from the rows $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

In the matrix $B$:
Claim(1): The row $i_{11}$ contains a non-zero element, say that $b \neq 0$, but we can divide this row by $b$ and have $1$ in place of $b$, thus
$\displaystyle{\tilde{B}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
& & & j_{1}-column & & \\
& & & \downarrow & & \\
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & \cdots & \star & \cdots & b_{1,l} \\
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & \cdots & \star & \cdots & b_{2,l} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{i_{11},1} & b_{i_{11},2} & \cdots & 1 & \cdots & b_{i_{11},l} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{n,1} & b_{n,2} & \cdots & \star & \cdots & b_{n,l} \\
\end{pmatrix}_{n \times l}}$,
because if all the elements were zero, then the $B_{I_{1} , J_{2}}$ will not be invertible.
Claim(2): The rows $i_{21}$ and $i_{22}$ do not contain only zeros,
because if it was then the $B_{I_{2} , J_{2}}$ will NOT be invertible due to one row will have zeroes.
Now we are looking the rows $\displaystyle{i_{21}}$ and $\displaystyle{i_{22}}$:
If the $b_{i_{21} , j_{1}} \neq 0$ and $b_{i_{22} , j_{1}} \neq 0$, we can, without loss of generality, do elementary row operations and change them to zero, and we can use the same argument as previously.
So each time we can make the matrix $B$ as
$\displaystyle{\tilde{B}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & \cdots & b_{1,j_{1}} & \cdots & b_{1,l} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{i_{11},1} & b_{i_{11},2} & \cdots & 1 & \cdots & b_{i_{11},l} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{i_{21},1} & b_{i_{21},2} & \cdots & \color{green}0 & \cdots & b_{i_{21},l} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{i_{22},1} & b_{i_{22},2} & \cdots & \color{green}0 & \cdots & b_{i_{22},l} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{n,1} & b_{n,2} & \cdots & b_{n,j_{1}} & \cdots & b_{n,l}
\end{pmatrix}_{n \times l}}$, then each non-zero element at the row $i_{21}$ or $i_{22}$ satisfies the one of the two properties.
In the matrix $A$: we want to find row $j_{2}$ which is linear independent with the row $j_{1}$. And now for this $j_{2}$, we check if $b_{i_{21},j_{2}} \neq 0$ or $b_{i_{22},j_{2}} \neq 0$ and we are done.
How could we prove the general problem? Do you have any ideas? The same argument is it working?
